# Eliminar la opción de descarga en dompdf de un informe generado

Tags: php, pdf

Buenos días, tengo una duda, ¿Es posible mostrar un PDF haciendo imposible que el usuario lo descargue o imprima? (Me encuentro usando la biblioteca de dompdf).

[image: imagen de referencia]

```
<?php 
    require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'landscape');
    $dompdf -> load_html(ob_get_clean());
    $dompdf -> render();
    $pdf = $dompdf -> output();
    $filename = 'nombre.pdf';
    $dompdf -> stream( $filename, array('Attachment' => false)); 
    exit(0);
?>
```

Comment: Creo que no ya que es el navegador quien controla esto. Pero ante la duda, a ver si alguien pone luz.

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que @Xerif. Hace un tiempo tuve la misma necesidad y no encontré forma :/ . Pero quizás ahora exista alguna biblioteca/plugin/algo... esperemos que alguien sepa... te di mi +1 y marqué la pregunta en favoritos ;)

Comment: Es casi seguro que no, porque dompdf genera el archivo .pdf, no el programa para visualizarlo. Quizas, en vez de tratar de hacer algo relacionado a esos iconos, exista alguna propiedad en los meta datos de un pdf que te ayude a no imprimirlo o a no ser manipulable de alguna forma.

Comment: Tienes que anexar el header e indicarle que tipo de archivo será, al indicarle o agregarle el header y el tipo de archivo lo podrás visualizar en el navegador, si es un archivo por ejemplo zip lo que hace es descargalo.

Answer (score 1):

Si se puede, embebiendo el pdf y agregando la opción toolbar=0

```
<embed src="manual.pdf#toolbar=0" width="500" height="375">
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa header.

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
```